# How do I get the extension from a URL using Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, uri

I want to find the extension `.html` from this URL:

```
http://testasp.vulnweb.com/Templatize.asp?item=html/about.html
```

Comment: I have tried class URI as well as class Pathname in ruby....but i still didn't get .html extension from URI ...I can easily find .asp extension from this URI but i don't want that...

Comment: require 'uri'
require 'pathname'
pathname = Pathname.new(link)
extension = pathname.extname

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
URI.parse(url).query[/\.\w+/]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has the [URI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/frames) module, which is part of the standard distribution, plus the [Addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/Addressable/URI.html#query_values%3D-instance_method) gem:

```
url = 'http://testasp.vulnweb.com/Templatize.asp?item=html/about.html'

require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse(url)
queries = Hash[uri.query.split('&').map{ |q| q.split('=') }]
puts queries['item']

require "addressable/uri"
uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
puts uri.query_values['item']
```

Both will output:

```
html/about.html
```

when run.

URI is convenient, but Addressable is very powerful and full-featured. If I need to do a lot of URL parsing or manipulation Addressable is the way to go.

Once you have `html/about.html` you can extract the extension several ways:

```
path = 'html/about.html'

path[/(\..+)$/, 1] # => ".html"
path.split('.').last # => "html"
File.extname(path) # => ".html"
```

Notice that using `split` removes `.` so it would need to be prepended to `html` again.

Answer (score -2):

Generic answer for most programming language (I am not a ruby guy)-

```
String.substring(String.lastIndexOf("."), String.length);
```

Comment: Thanx for the replay but i have to iterate through array of URI's in which some URI's may not contain any path ...so this type of code may throw some error

Comment: String queryString = uri.split("?"); queryString.substring( ...); [above code ]; put in a for loop; Will work. But post some code that you hve tried earlier. It is easy to modify code.

Comment: I have tried the code require 'uri' require 'pathname' pathname = Pathname.new(link) extension = pathname.extname ....it is in ruby...